# simple parse error with my form submit using ajax and file upload

Tags: php, ajax

I'm able to get the file uploaded and in to the directory I want so that part seems to work but I'm not sure why I'm getting a parse error in the js console in chrome. Because of this error my bottom javascript won't execute and I need it to do so.

Here's the ajax:

```
var files;

// Add events
$('input[type=file]').on('change', prepareUpload);

// Grab the files and set them to our variable
function prepareUpload(event)
{
  files = event.target.files;
}

$('form').on('submit', uploadFiles);

// Catch the form submit and upload the files
function uploadFiles(event)
{
  event.stopPropagation(); // Stop stuff happening
  event.preventDefault(); // Totally stop stuff happening

// START A LOADING SPINNER HERE

// Create a formdata object and add the files
var data = new FormData();
$.each(files, function(key, value)
{
    data.append(key, value);
});

$.ajax({
    url: 'submit.php?files',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false, // Don't process the files
    contentType: false, // Set content type to false as jQuery will tell the server its a query string request
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
        alert(data);
        script = $(data).text();
        $.globalEval(script);
        if(typeof data.error === 'undefined')
        {
            // Success so call function to process the form
            submitForm(event, data);
        }
        else
        {
            // Handle errors here
            console.log('ERRORS: ' + data.error);
        }

    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        // Handle errors here
        console.log('ERRORS: ' + textStatus);
        // STOP LOADING SPINNER
    }
});
}
```

Here's the html:

```
<?php 
echo '<span class="new_profile_save_upload_image_span"><img     src="'.$url_root.'/images/615721406-612x612.jpg"/ class="new_profile_save_upload_image_img"></span>';
?>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="new_profile_save_upload_image_input_form" id="new_profile_save_upload_image_input_form">
<input type="file" id="new_profile_save_upload_image_input" name="new_profile_save_upload_image_input" multiple="" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg"/>
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

And here is the php:

```
<?php 

// get mysqli db connection string
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "psych_admin", "asd123", "psych");
if($mysqli->connect_error){
    exit('Error db');
}

// Get theme settings and theme colours and assign the theme colour to the 
theme name
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT name FROM user_profiles WHERE rowid=(SELECT 
    MAX(rowid) FROM user_profiles);");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while($row_1 = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $arr_1[] = $row_1;
}
foreach($arr_1 as $arrs_1)
{
    $username = $arrs_1['name'];
}

$data = array();

if(isset($_GET['files']))
{  
    $error = false;
    $files = array();

    // Make dir for file uploads to be held
    if (!file_exists(''.dirname(__FILE__) . '/content/profiles/'.$username.'/avatar')) 
    {
        mkdir(''.dirname(__FILE__) . '/content/profiles/'.$username.'/avatar', 0777, true);
    }
    $uploaddir = './content/profiles/'.$username.'/avatar/';
    foreach($_FILES as $file)
    {
        if(move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $uploaddir .basename($file['name'])))
        {
            $files[] = $uploaddir .$file['name'];
        }
        else
        {
            $error = true;
        }
    }
    $data = ($error) ? array('error' => 'There was an error uploading your files') : array('files' => $files);
}
else
{
    $data = array('success' => 'Form was submitted', 'formData' => $_POST);
}

echo json_encode($data);

?>

<script>
var scope1 = '<?php echo $url_root;?>';
var scope2 = '<?php echo $username;?>';
var scope3 = '<?php echo $file['name'];?>';
var new_profile_save_upload_image_span_data = '<img src="' + scope1 + '/content/profiles/' + scope2 + '/avatar/' + scope3 + '"     class="new_profile_save_upload_image_img">';
$('.new_profile_save_upload_image_span').empty();
$('.new_profile_save_upload_image_span').append(new_profile_save_upload_image_span_data);

</script>
```

alert(data) doesn't seem to be popping up, so there's something wrong previous to that execution.

I tried this code with simply 'submit.php' but it doesn't seem to work without the 'files' addition to it.

Also do I have the filename correct? Should the file's filename be $file['name'] in php? I'm trying to get the file name as a string and place it in when the default image is (as an image to be displayed), using an img html tag and inserting it via jquery, as you can see at the bottom under .

The ajax should execute this script at the bottom but it doesn't due to the error.

Also is there a nicer way of writing the bottom jquery scripts that I have written?

Error I'm getting:

`ERRORS: Syntax Error: Unexpected Token < in JSON at position 103`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're getting an error, it might be a smart idea to post the exact error in your question. This will _greatly_ help us in finding the issue.

Comment: @icecub I added the error to the post.

Comment: Change `console.log('ERRORS: ' + textStatus);` to `console.log('ERRORS: ' + errorThrown);`. Run it again. Edit your question and post the actual error instead of the status.

Comment: You're expecting json back (`dataType: 'json'`). You echo json data but you also output javascript after. That will be a part of the response, rendering the response invalid json (hence the parse error when jquery tries to parse the response as json).

Comment: You also use `data` (which would be a json object, if the response was correct) as a selector string `$(data).text();`. What are you actually expecting the response to be? You can't return multiple different data types at once.

Comment: @icecub I added the error message. @Magnus I thought it would work like all my other ajax and execute the php script, which uploads the file to a dir, then outputs a script to be executed `script = $(data).text();$.globalEval(script);`. Are you saying that the file upload causes some type of response that is included in the data variable? As it is, I thought it would just respond with the jquery scripts.

Comment: Well, as your error clearly states: `Unexpected Token < in JSON`. So as @MagnusEriksson told you, you've setup your Ajax to expect a JSON string as a result. Not a regular string (some JS code). Easiest solution would probably be to just remove `dataType: 'json',`. Don't quote me on that though! Been a while since I used jQuery

Comment: The upload isn't causing anything. It's your output that causes it. You first have `echo json_encode($data);` and then you have your `<script>`-tag. You also use the response in different ways. You first treat it as a string `$(data)` (which I'm guessing should create a jquery object from the `<script>`-tag to get the content). Then after, you're using it as an object: `typeof data.error ...`. You can't have it both ways. If you want it as an object, remove the script. If you want the script, remove `dataType: 'json'` and remove the `echo`.

Comment: It works thanks @icecub! I didn't know that the datatype defines response, I thought it was just input. Thanks guys.

Comment: All credit to @MagnusEriksson for this one. He saw the problem before I even got the actual error :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return JSON and HTML at the same time, you could put the HTML into an element of the `$data` array.

```
<?php 

// get mysqli db connection string
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "psych_admin", "asd123", "psych");
if($mysqli->connect_error){
    exit('Error db');
}

// Get theme settings and theme colours and assign the theme colour to the 
theme name
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT name FROM user_profiles WHERE rowid=(SELECT 
    MAX(rowid) FROM user_profiles);");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while($row_1 = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $arr_1[] = $row_1;
}
foreach($arr_1 as $arrs_1)
{
    $username = $arrs_1['name'];
}

$data = array();

if(isset($_GET['files']))
{  
    $error = false;
    $files = array();

    // Make dir for file uploads to be held
    if (!file_exists(''.dirname(__FILE__) . '/content/profiles/'.$username.'/avatar')) 
    {
        mkdir(''.dirname(__FILE__) . '/content/profiles/'.$username.'/avatar', 0777, true);
    }
    $uploaddir = './content/profiles/'.$username.'/avatar/';
    foreach($_FILES as $file)
    {
        if(move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $uploaddir .basename($file['name'])))
        {
            $files[] = $uploaddir .$file['name'];
        }
        else
        {
            $error = true;
        }
    }
    $data = ($error) ? array('error' => 'There was an error uploading your files') : array('files' => $files);
}
else
{
    $data = array('success' => 'Form was submitted', 'formData' => $_POST);
    $data['html'] = <<<EOS
<script>
var scope1 = '$url_root';
var scope2 = '$username';
var scope3 = '{$file['name']}';
var new_profile_save_upload_image_span_data = '<img src="' + scope1 + '/content/profiles/' + scope2 + '/avatar/' + scope3 + '"     class="new_profile_save_upload_image_img">';
\$('.new_profile_save_upload_image_span').empty();
\$('.new_profile_save_upload_image_span').append(new_profile_save_upload_image_span_data);

</script>
EOS;

}

echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

Then in the JavaScript you do:

```
script = $(data.html).text();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use try-catch block in your PHP code, and send status with the response set to true or false. Also, send the `$url_root` and `$username` variables within the JSON object.

See [this beginner's guide on Image Uploading with PHP and AJAX](https://developer.hyvor.com/php/image-upload-ajax-php-mysql) to learn everything about creating AJAX handler, validating, saving and sending a response back to the client side.